# Background processing being killed after seconds when minimizing a IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

**Introduction**

I made a [VOIP dialer](https://apps.apple.com/br/app/vmax-fone/id1511737051) app with `react-native`. I'm using [react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) to show the user the default IOS call screen when receiving a call (On background and foreground), and I'm using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/willnaoosmit/react-native-push-notification) to pop-up a local notification when a call is received too.

**The problem**

When I minimize the app (With the home button) and the app receives a call, it doesn't show either the local notification or the call screen.
*but*, if the call comes right after the minimize action, the screen and the notification show up.

**Technical explanation of what happens**

Reading the logs, I see that IOS kills my app background processing when it prints the following line:

`15:08:23.085311-0300   symptomsd   com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone: Foreground: false`

After this, nothing works on either foreground or background

**Code explanation**

Probably, the problem isn't with react-native-callkeep or with react-native-push-notification itself (Because they're work as intended). I think it's something with IOS Itself.

I found [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130104) thread which defines exactly what happens to me.

**My enabled capabilities**

[image]

**What I'm using**

`react-native version 0.61.5`

`Xcode version 11.5 (11E608c) on a MacOS 10.15.5 Catalina`

`IOS 13.4.1 on a Iphone 8`

`I'm using a release version of my project (The debug version does the same thing too)`

**My AppDelegate.m** (Only the part after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` matters the most)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import "RNCallKeep.h"

#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}

#if DEBUG
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"VMAXFone"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  return YES;
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
  restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
  return [RNCallKeep application:application
           continueUserActivity:userActivity
             restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  completionHandler();
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

@end
```

I don't think this is necessary but every information counts, so here's **how I set-up react-native-callkeep** (This function is called when the app starts)

```
function initCallKitIntegration() {
  return async function (dispatch, getState) {
    let activeCall = null
    const uuids = {}
    const options = {
      ios: {
        appName: 'VMAX Fone',
        imageName: 'phone_account_icon',
        includesCallsInRecents: true,
        supportsVideo: false
      }
    }

    RNCallKeep.setup(options).then(accepted => {})

    let incomingCall = null

    const {endpoint} = getState().pjsip
    const {appState} = getState().pjsip

    endpoint.on("call_received", (call) => {

      RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', () => {
        //accept call here
      })

      RNCallKeep.addEventListener('endCall', () => {
        //decline call here
      })

      RNCallKeep.addEventListener('didPerformDTMFAction', ({ digits, callUUID }) => {
        //send dtmf digits here
      })

      RNCallKeep.addEventListener('didPerformSetMutedCallAction', ({ muted, callUUID }) => {
        //mute and unmute call here
      })

      RNCallKeep.addEventListener('didToggleHoldCallAction', ({ hold, callUUID }) => {
        //hold and unhold call here
      })

      endpoint.on("call_changed", (call) => {
        //Change Call state here
      })

      endpoint.on("call_terminated", (call) => {
        
        //endCall here

        RNCallKeep.endCall(uuids[call.getCallId()])

        delete uuids[call.getCallId()]
      })

      if (appState != 'active'){
        RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(uuids[call.getCallId()], call.getRemoteNumber(), call.getRemoteNumber(), 'number', false)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**The logs**

```
15:08:22 VMAXFone   Snapshotting a view (0x107269800, UIKeyboardImpl) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
15:08:22 powerd Process runningboardd.28 Created SystemIsActive "application<com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone>28-56-1455:FBSceneSnapshotAction:sceneID:com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone-default" age:00:00:00  id:51539643472 [System: PrevIdle SysAct]
15:08:22 SpringBoard    [sceneID:com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone-default] Sending scene action [SceneLifecycleEventOnly][0xa901] through WorkspaceServer: 0x2819e4300
15:08:22 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8323 DR=91.4263 factor=0.084515:08:23 SpringBoard    Application process state changed for com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone: <SBApplicationProcessState: 0x280321380; pid: 476; taskState: Running; visibility: Background>
15:08:23 SpringBoard    [com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone] Generating image data for snapshot: <XBApplicationSnapshot: 0x10033e300; identifier: 5EA00F96-F22F-4CDA-907D-4E24FCC9119C; contentType: SceneContent>
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8347 DR=91.3501 factor=0.0846
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8370 DR=91.2738 factor=0.0847
15:08:23 SpringBoard    [com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone] Generating image data for snapshot: <XBApplicationSnapshot: 0x107662e60; identifier: DAA57ADA-4C38-4904-9139-C0782D20A8CA; variantID: downscaled; 
15:08:23 SpringBoard    [com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone] Snapshot data for <XBApplicationSnapshot: 0x10033e300; …4E24FCC9119C> written to file: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E4F918EF-7431-4A05-9845-344EB8B058DD/Library/SplashBoard/Snapshots/sceneID:com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone-default/5EA00F96-F22F-4CDA-907D-4E24FCC9119C@2x.ktx
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8394 DR=91.1976 factor=0.0848
15:08:23 powerlogHelperd    {"msg":"CLCopyAppsUsingLocation", "event":"activity"}
15:08:23 SpringBoard    [com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone] Snapshot data for <XBApplicationSnapshot: 0x107662e60; …C0782D20A8CA> written to file: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E4F918EF-7431-4A05-9845-344EB8B058DD/Library/SplashBoard/Snapshots/sceneID:com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone-default/downscaled/DAA57ADA-4C38-4904-9139-C0782D20A8CA@2x.ktx
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8418 DR=91.1215 factor=0.0849
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8441 DR=91.0455 factor=0.0850
15:08:23 kernel memorystatus: set assertion priority(3) target VMAXFone:476
15:08:23 runningboardd  [application<com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone>:476] Set jetsam priority to 3 [0] flag[1]
15:08:23 runningboardd  [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:56] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
15:08:23 runningboardd  Calculated state for application<com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone>: running-active (role: NonUserInteractive)
15:08:23 runningboardd  [application<com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone>:476] Set darwin role to: NonUserInteractive
15:08:23 runningboardd  [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:56] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
15:08:23 runningboardd  Calculated state for daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>: running-active (role: UserInteractiveNonFocal)
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8465 DR=90.9694 factor=0.0851
15:08:23 mediaserverd   -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone with pid '476' is now Background Running. Background entitlement: YES ActiveLongFormVideoSession: NO WhitelistedLongFormVideoApp NO
15:08:23 mediaserverd   AudioSessionServerImp.cpp:3517:HandleAudioSessionApplicationStateChangeListener: { "action":"application_state_changed", "session":{"ID":"0x1f672","PID":476,"name":"VMAXFone"}, "details":{"new_state":"Background Running"} }
15:08:23 mediaserverd   -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client (null) with pid '477' is now Background Running. Background entitlement: NO ActiveLongFormVideoSession: NO WhitelistedLongFormVideoApp NO
15:08:23 mediaserverd   -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Sending stop command to (null) with pid '477' because client is not allowed to play in the background AND does not continue AirPlaying video when device locks
15:08:23 mediaserverd   -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client (null) with pid '405' is now Background Running. Background entitlement: YES ActiveLongFormVideoSession: NO WhitelistedLongFormVideoApp NO
15:08:23 mediaserverd   SSServerImp.cpp:1179:SystemSoundServerKillSoundsForPID: pid 477(ContactViewViewS)
15:08:23 SpringBoard    <private> setEnabledTopics <private> ignoredTopics <private> opportunisticTopics <private> sendToDaemon: YES
15:08:23 apsd   Looking up connection on peer: 1b848900   found <private>
15:08:23 apsd   <private>: connection set enabled topics from <private> to <private>
15:08:23 apsd   <private>: connection set opportunistic topics from <private> to <private>
15:08:23 apsd   <private> setEnabledTopics:<private> ignoredTopics:<private> opportunisticTopics:<private> forCategory UsesALS pretend NO change Downgraded
15:08:23 apsd   <private> cancelling any pending filter updates
15:08:23 apsd   <private> received topic update for Server pretend YES but there is no change.
15:08:23 apsd   <private> no change detected between the new and old server filter - cancelling any pending updates
15:08:23 apsd   <private> flush any pending work that ALS told us to queue for its managed topics <private>, processMode systemToken
15:08:23 apsd   <private> flush any pending work that ALS told us to queue for its managed topics <private>, processMode userToken
15:08:23 apsd   <private> received topic update for Normal pretend NO but there is no change.
15:08:23 SpringBoard    <private> setEnabledTopics <private> ignoredTopics <private> opportunisticTopics <private> sendToDaemon: NO
15:08:23 locationd  {"msg":"#CLIUA Marking change", "clientKey":"com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone", "reason":"Decaying in-use status from process state", "assertionLevel":3, "coming":1}
15:08:23 locationd  {"msg":"#CLIUA Marking change", "clientKey":"com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone", "reason":"Process state from RunningBoard", "assertionLevel":4, "coming":0}
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8489 DR=90.8935 factor=0.0852
15:08:23 CommCenter #I BundleID: <private> is no longer a foreground app
15:08:23 backboardd Lcurrent=258.9457 Lr=2.8513 DR=90.8176 factor=0.0853
15:08:23 symptomsd  NBSM Current state: idle, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0
15:08:23 symptomsd  NBSM Eligible to go to active
15:08:23 symptomsd  NBSM Current state: idle, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0, eligible for active but constraints unsatisfied (0,0,0)
15:08:23 symptomsd  NBSM Current state: idle, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0, ineligible for positive as nil pred, wifi (0x0) cell (0x0)
15:08:23 symptomsd  NBSM Current state: idle, changed: systemForeground to 0 for net type 0, ineligible for broken as nil pred, wifi (0x0) cell (0x0)
15:08:23 symptomsd  com.vmaxtelecom.vmaxfone: Foreground: false
```

If there's a concept, or something that will keep my app from being killed by the IOS itself, I will be grateful of your help.

**[EDIT]**

So, I was looking and found some things that helped me:

- My app, even with the background modes, needs to USE them to be a valid app to run on background and foreground.
- The OS needs to recognize the app as a valid app to run the background mode *(In my case, be a valid VOIP dialer)*.

**What exactly was happening**

My app processes wasn't recognized as any of the background modes i was using, so it was snapshotted, `not killed`. As viewed on the below image, taken from [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence) on the Apple website, there was no event to be handled, so it was snapshotted.

[image]

So now, my problem is how can i make my app be recognized as a valid VOIP dialer app by the Apple store itself.

This question is now ended.

Comment: A well written question, thanks.